# Github Passport strategy for Composer

Tags: rest, github, passport.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to configure user authentication via REST API using Github strategy per documentation at:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html

I Installed the passport-github strategy by executing - `npm install -g passport-github`

But noticed that the install did not create the needed (`"authPath": "/auth/github"`) Folder on my VM.

I read on Github website: https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github

> The author of Passport-Github has not maintained the original module for a long time. Features in his module don't work since Github upgraded their API to version 3.0. We forked it and re-published it to NPM with a new name passport-github2

Can someone confirm if this needs correction? And if so what exact steps I need follow?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a typo in the document. The flag for turning on security while launching composer-rest-server should be -a true instead of -S true.

Comment: Yessir... the Github-Passport strategy is working just fine for me now! Though I noted half a dozen other users struggling with the same issue during last couple of days.  The issue is tracked (closed now) - Pl. see: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2109

Answer (score 0):

If you check the age of the last commit, you see that the original repo [jaredhanson/passport-github](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github) shows the following last commit:

> Latest commit [c103215](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github/commit/c10321591d0521a2235613830562c2e8e2195c16) on Feb 3, 2016

The new repo [cfsghost/passport-github](https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github) has a README.md update 21 days ago (mid August 2017) and before that the last commit on:

> [d572f18](https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github/commit/d572f18d0031c2bb891bf7a966eb4d5d4211381b) on Mar 1, 2016 *...and that was a version bump*

So from what I can tell, the "new" package is not really newer. But then it was forked in August 2014.

After creating the folder you mentioned. Does it work?

Comment: Thanks Peter!  Did you mean I should create the Folder /auth/github manually and try ?

Comment: I'm following steps mentioned at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html   but facing 2 issues. 

1. REST Server does not stop me and throw “HTTP 401 Authorization Required” message, even after I enable security with  the -S true switch: composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n health-network -i PeerAdmin -s randomString -S true
 
2. Trying to Authenticate to the REST server by navigating to localhost:3000/auth/github  - throws up error as seen in screenshot